# What is the right way to work with DB and DB connection pool?

Tags: crystal-lang

In my code I open DB at start of program and pass `db` variable to other methods. I think it's stupid and not right. But what should I do? Should I open db connection in each method? But this way also doesn't look right... And I have a lot of errors: `DB::ConnectionRefused, DB::PoolTimeout, DB::PoolRetryAttemptsExceeded`
    So it something wrong with my code.

```
def main_meth
db = DB.open("postgres://blabla@localhost:5432/bla?retry_attempts=8&retry_delay=3&max_pool_size=50&max_idle_pool_size=10&checkout_timeout=0.1") # there is always same story with or without params.
begin

db.scalar("")
...
another_meth(params, db)

channel = Channel(Nil).new(20)
    groups.each do |group|
      spawn one_more_meth(group, channel, db)
    end
    groups.size.times { channel.receive }

 ensure
      db.close
    end
end

def another_meth(p, db)
deeper_meth(db)
end

def one_more_meth(group, channel, db)
...
db.query_all
...
channel.send(nil)
end
```

Comment: It should be correct to pass a single DB around the whole program: it handles pooling internally. Do any queries work at all or do the errors only happen when doing lots of queries? If not, does it work from another language, using the same connection URL?

Comment: It happens with a lot of queries. Yes, there are 10 independent programs on crystal + 1 rails app. But I have 2000 connections max set in my pg

Comment: But on my local machine I have same errors with only one app running.

Comment: But it doesn't happen on *all* queries from crystal, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are. It looks like connections pool released connections too slow.

Comment: I think this is a bug, or something regarding more investigation. I'd suggest making an issue here: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal-db/issues

Comment: I have suggestion that on my local computer it can be because hdd is too slow ( my new comp is broken). And because of it I open and close DB in each method for connection releasing. But on production it can generate "connection refused".

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and I found is that when doing `db.query` you have to make sure to either use a block: `db.query("") do |rs|; end` or close the result set: `rs = db.query("");rs.close`

Comment: @fridgerator Thanks for advise. But I don't use db.query this way. I use db.scalar, db.exec, db.query_all and Class.from_rs(db.query ""). As far as I understand no one from these queries should be closed manually.

Comment: `Class.from_rs(db.query "")` might not close the result set.   You could try saving the query to a variable, and after `from_rs` closing it: `rs = db.query("");Class.from_rs(rs);rs.close`

Comment: @fridgerator It looks like you are right! Thanks. You are welcome to add an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue and I found is that when doing db.query you have to make sure to either:

save the result sets to a variable and after usage close them

```
rs = db.query("")
Class.from_rs(rs)
rs.close
```

OR use a block

```
db.query("") do |rs|
    Class.from_rs(rs)
end
```

Comment: Here is new fix that makes rs.close unneeded https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal-db/commit/c63ea487486f0d1527d41b93b16a4eceed3516b7

Comment: thats great, nice!